# Prove/disprove if $a\vee b \Rightarrow c$ then $a\Rightarrow c$ or $b\Rightarrow c$ and vice versa

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> $a,b,c$ are statements, $\Rightarrow$ is a tautological consequence (not a logical implication and it's not a proposition).
>
> Prove/disprove:
>
> 1. if $a\vee b \Rightarrow c$ then $a\Rightarrow c$ or $b\Rightarrow c$
> 2. if $a\Rightarrow c$ or $b\Rightarrow c$ then  $a\vee b \Rightarrow c$

I'm not sure how to prove it but I think both are true, since $c$ is a tautological consequence then it's true regardless of of what $a$ and $b$ are. $c$ is true in both cases especially if $a=b=F$.

Comment: are $a,b,c$ sentences in propositional logic ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus they're statements so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1. [using the "more standard" $\vDash$ for *tautological consequence*] :

> if $a ∨ b \vDash c$, then $a \vDash c$ or $b \vDash c$,

consider a valuation $v$ such that one of $a,b$ is *true*.

We can assume, without loss of generality, that $v(a)=$**t**; then $v(a \lor b)=$**t**.

From $a ∨ b \vDash c$ it follows that $v(c)=$**t**, and thus : $a \vDash c$, and finally $a \vDash c$ or $b \vDash c$.

The same if we assume $v(b)=$**t**.

---

For 2. :

> if $a \vDash c$ or $b \vDash c$, then $a ∨ b \vDash c$,

it is not true, as we can see with the following counter-example.

Consider : as $a$ the formula $q \land \lnot q$, as $b$ the formula $r$ and as $c$ the formula $p \land \lnot p$.

In this case we have :

> $a \vDash c$ and **not** $b \vDash c$,

and thus : $a \vDash c$ or $b \vDash c$, but clearly :

> $(q \land \lnot q) \lor r \nvDash (p \land \lnot p)$.

Comment: We can have a tautology also if $c=F$ and $a\vee b=F$ or if $c=T$ and $a\vee b=F$ no?

Comment: It is a bit confusing, for $ψ$ to be a tautological consequence of $φ$ , this: $φ→ψ$ must always be true? So as long as it can't be that $φ=T, ψ=F$ it is a tautological consequence?

Comment: As in Stephen's answer, what if for 2: $v(b)=v(c)=F$ and $v(a)=T$?

Comment: It can't be that: $c=p\wedge \neg p$ for example?

Comment: Your argument for 2. where $a,b,c$ are atoms can't be right. Them being atoms or 'complex' formulas shouldn't have no bearing on it. In fact, the mistake is that after '$v(a)=1$ or $v(b)=1$', you proceed as if you had $a\models c$, but it's not necessarily true that that happens, it could be that you're in the sub-case '$v(a)=1$ and $b\models c$'. It seems that you're reading 'or' as 'and'. This is also noticeable in your proof of 1. which I don't think is quite right either. I'll elaborate on this if required.

Comment: For 2, $b$ could also be $k\wedge \neg k$ and will still work right?

Comment: It's $⊨(p∧¬p)$ in the answer. There can't be a tautological consequence if all the assumptions are always false and the consequence is false too?

Comment: @GinKin - no, because in that case a∨b will be $(q∧¬q)∨(k∧¬k)$ which is $F∨F$, and thus is always *false*. Thus we have that $[(q∧¬q)∨(k∧¬k)]⊨(p∧¬p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Claim 2 is false as you can see from valuation with $v(b)=v(c)=F$ and $v(a) = T$. Claim 1 is true. It may well be near a rule of inference that $a \vee b \rightarrow c$ if and only if $(a \rightarrow c) \wedge (b \rightarrow c)$, and it's easy to show $d \wedge e \rightarrow d \vee e$. And it's tautology since no quantification rules involved.

Comment: Thinking in terms of consequence (essentially the relation that holds when material implication is valid regardless of the nonlogical axioms) doesn't change things. You can't assume that c is a consequence of a if all you know is that either c is a consequence of a or c is a consequence of b, as in 2.